# Self defined messages

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,

I'm a bit new in ROS and I want to know how to create a self described message and use it in ROS to exchange information between ROS nodes. I've found this ros answer [1](https://answers.ros.org/question/31779/how-to-use-a-message-that-i-made/) and this video [2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ilRAlo5hi5o) about how to create and use you own ROS message. But there's still some question that remains unanswer or unclear for me.

1. You have to call a header file to start using your own message as the video and the answer question show, but what should I code in that header file (my_msg.h) and its realated cpp file (my_msg.cpp)? Or they must stay empty and its a trick ROS use to call self described messages? If anyone could done or refer me to a github easy example of an self defined message I will be very pleased.
2. Do you have to add any dependence or export any dependence of that package? If so, how can I do it?

Thanks in advance for your help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/333646/self-defined-messages/) by [drodgu](https://answers.ros.org/users/43205/drodgu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 59 on 2019-09-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

1. No, you don't have to create header, when you build your message it will do that for you.
2. If the message you built is in the same package as your node, then you don't need to add package dependency, but if message was built in a different package, then you need to add that package as a dependency.

---

Originally posted by [Choco93](https://answers.ros.org/users/31829/choco93/) with karma: 685 on 2019-09-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [drodgu](https://answers.ros.org/users/43205/drodgu/) on 2019-09-23**:
Thank you very much! I add also this video in which is explained how to setup your own message.
[Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F3zyAV4alCs)